# Prove that subspace of $s^*\subset l_p$, $p\ge 1$ of real sequences with a finite support is not closed.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Prove that subspace of $s^*\subset l_p$, $p\ge 1$ of real sequences with a finite support is not closed. I have to show, I suppose, that it doesn't contain all the limit points. I try to think of something but I get that as long as the number of zeros is infinite, it will always stay like that. No constructions of sequence  smart enough to change it seems to exist. Is there some concept or idea I am missing? I could really use some help here.

Comment: For $p < \infty$: Choose any element of $l_p$ that has no zeroes. Now consider the truncations...

Comment: For $p=\infty$, choose any sequence that has no zeros and has limit zero. Again consider the truncations.

Comment: Could I assume that a sequence $\{x_n=(a_1,a_2,...,a_n,0,...,0,...):a_i=1\}$ simply exists? 
What makes me doubt it is the infinity of the number of zeros. As if it could never tend to $(1,1,1,...)$.

Comment: I don't understand your question or doubt? A sequence is a function $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I don't fully understand what truncating is in practice. I thought it considers looking at a seqeuence whose number of non-zero element grow.

Comment: I edited my previous comment as you can see. I was confused. I am truly sorry. You've been super helpful so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a sequence $x:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$, define the truncation
$\tau_k(x)(n) = \begin{cases} x_n, & n \le k \\
0, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.

It should be clear that for **any** sequence $x$, we have  $\tau_k(x) \in l_p$
for any $p \ge 1$ or $p=\infty$.

Note that $\tau_k(x)$ has finite support.

Let $x^*(n) = {1 \over n^2}$. Note that $x^* \in l_p$ for any $p \ge 1$ or $p=\infty$. Note that $x^*$ does **not**
have finite support.

For any $p \ge 1$ or $p=\infty$, check that 
 $\|x^*-\tau_k(x^*) \|_p \to 0$.

Comment: It looks really good. Only wondering: shouldn't I show that the truncation is in $s^*$ (x is outside of s^* potentially. )

Comment: It must be, it has only finitely many non zero values???

Comment: Okay. I was just impressed it wasn't to be noted so I thought I had a miscomprehension of your method. Thank you a lot.

Comment: You are very welcome.

Comment: Really hate to disturb, but I have arrived at $(\sum_{i=k+1}^{\infty}|x_i|^p)^{1\over p}\le \sum_{i=k+1}^{\infty}|x_i|^p$. Is it direct that this sum tends to zero as $k$ tends to infinity? Or should I prove it specifically? 
I am not quite sure how it is derived formally by analysis.

Comment: @Meitar: I don't know what you are doing, and that statement is not correct for general $x$. How is that related to this question?

Comment: Forget it, sorry to bother. I'll make up my mind and then ask you if something isn't clear.

Comment: Similarly, (computing the norm of the the difference)I have arrived now at $(\sum_{i=k+1}^{\infty}{1\over n^{2p}})^{1\over p}$. I do know this series converges, but as a function of k, is it dirct that it converges to zero?

Comment: Yes. If $s=\sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n|$ converges, then $s-\sum_{n=1}^k |x_n|$ must converge to zero!

Comment: Yes, I just recalled first calculus course. Thank you so much for your help.